# I'm totally faint in using multer-s3 to upload image to aws s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, express, multer-s3

what does "upload.array('photos', 3) " in the following code denotes ....

My html code. (code reduced for brevity)

```
 <form action="/upload" method="POST">
 <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" accept="image/*">
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

my expressjs code

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  secretAccessKey: "yyyyyyyyyy", 
  "region": "zzzzzzzzz" ,
  signatureVersion: 'v4'
});

var s3=new AWS.S3();

var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'imgcontainer',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString())
    }
  })
})

app.post('/upload', upload.array('photos', 3), function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Successfully uploaded ' + req.files.length + ' files!')
})
```

output:

```
 Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

- The file field name is 'pic' and not 'photos' (which is the field name being used on the Express side). Change one name or the other.
- The `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute needs to be explicitly set on the `<form>` tag, otherwise browsers will send the form as application/x-www-form-urlencoded which will not include file input data.

Make these changes and `req.files` should be populated as outlined in the `multer` documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your response mscdex, "upload.array("pic",3)" ... then what 3 represents.....

Comment: [The documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount) explains it, it's the `maxCount` parameter (enforces a max file limit for that file field name).

Comment: Same error " Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" even after changing photos to pic ..... sorry

Comment: I've updated my answer to include information about another issue.